# Any tools to monitor processes and resources consumed of virtual machines?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, process-monitoring

### Hi all,

I need a tool that can retrieve information about used resources of each VM and their processes,

- I use KVM as hyper-visor
- I also need it to have a programming API

I know it is a tough request :), but any contribution is more than welcome !

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If you're running *NIX based guests, couldn't you script a set of ssh sessions to login to each guest and grab whatever information you need?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) and other popular monitoring tools work on virtual machines in much the same way as on the real ones.